# How can I add fips codes to a dataset with "State,County" in RStudio?

Tags: r, excel, merge, fips

I have an excel imported dataset with a column labeled Names which lists "State,County". For example: Texas,Anderson. I created a variable called nam3 which lists "Texas,Anderson" and so on for each line of the dataset for different counties throughout the entire United States (but not all the counties).

I want to match the correct fips codes for the nam3 variable.
I imported another dataset that has columns for FIPS, STATE, and County for the entire United States.

How do I specify in RStudio to create a variable "FIPS" that is equal to the correct fips codes of the corresponding "nam3" variable given the dataset which lists the FIPS codes for the entire United States.

Comment: Are you just trying to make a mapping of one column to another?

Comment: I'm not sure what mapping means. I am trying to add the correct fips codes to a list of counties and states that I have in a list.